# Catalyst app: How do I enable com.apple.developer.default-data-protection entitlement?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, mac-catalyst

I am attempting to distribute a Catalyst app for beta testing. Since there's no Test Flight for Mac, my intent is to distribute a signed archive in order to minimize the amount warnings my users receive about running the app. I did the following:

1. Archived for MyMac,
2. Selected the archive from the "macOS Apps" list in the organizer,
3. Clicked "Distribute App,"
4. Chose "Developer ID."
5. Selected "Upload"
6. Selected "Automatically manage signing"

I expected it to be submitted for notarization, but instead received an error:

> Provisioning profiled failed qualification. Profile doesn't include
>   the com.apple.developer.default-data-protection entitlement.

I subsequently checked the Mac OS Provisioning profile via `developer.apple.com.` I have a profile that's labeled "XC OSX:" (assuming that means Xcode auto-generated) with a type field of "Developer ID Application." Sure enough, although it shows iCloud, in app purchases, etc., in the "Enabled Capabilities" section it does not have Data Protection.

But, in Xcode, when I select the target and go to "Signing and Capabilities," Data Protection is already listed. When I click the information "i" button next to the MacOS provision profile, it says com.apple.developer.default-data-protection is enabled. (it actually shows that for both the IOS and the MacOS provisioning profile).

[image]

Next, I looked at the Bundle Identifier on developer.apple.com and see Data Protection listed under capabilities:

[image]

I tried removing and re-adding Data Protection in Xcode, but the error still occurs.

I tried manually creating a Developer ID profile on developer.apple.com, but the resulting profile still lacks Data Protection.

I tried removing and re-adding Data Protection under the identifier on developer.apple.com. This successfully invalidated the existing profiles (both Xcode's and the one I created). When I again attempted signing, a new profile was created but it still lacks Data Protection and the error still occurs.

**What am I missing here? What else do I have to do to enable Data Protection in the provisioning profile?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burned a support ticket and found the answer. I read the message as:

> You failed. You don't have Data Protection (but you need it)

But per Apple, it actually means:

> You failed. You want Data Protection (because you turned it on) but
>   don't have it (because it's not supported in this config).

So, the solution for "Data protection is missing" was... turn Data Protection **off**.

Answer (score 3):

As you figured out, the problem here is that the `Data Protection` entitlement is not available for `MacOS`.

If you still want to use this for your `iOS` version of the app, you need to use a different `.entitlements` file for your `MacOS` build to your `iOS` build.

Firstly, duplicate your current `.entitlements` file. The easiest way is to hold the `Alt` key while dragging the `.entitlements` file slightly. It will make a copy. Rename it to something like `Original Name-MacOS.entitlements`.

The next step is to open your `Build Settings` and type `entitlements` into the search bar.

You'll see your original entitlements file showing for both `Debug` and `Release` builds. Select the `Debug` row, then click the `+` button. Click on `Any SDK` and change it to `Any macOS SDK`. Now change the name of the entitlements file to your `MacOS` variant.

Repeat the process for the `Release` build so it looks like below.

[image]

The final step is to remove the offending entitlement from your `MacOS` `.entitlements` file. This has to be done manually as the `Signing & Capabilities` tab will only show the entitlements from your original `iOS` file. So click you `MacOS` `.entitlements` file and delete the `Data Protection` entry.

`Clean` your project, `Build & Run`, `Export` etc.. and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, data protection APIs are not currently functional.

If you try to use them like this,

```
try data.write(to: fileUrl, options: .completeFileProtection
```

the code will compile and execute but the data is not being stored securely on the file system.

If you need to store data securely, there are several options available to you.
Passwords and related data can be stored in the Keychain and FileVault will encrypt all of the files on the disk transparently.

But if that's not sufficient for your needs. You can use the AES.GCM encryption API in CryptoKit to encrypt your content before writing it to disk.

```
let key = SymmatericKey(size: .bits256)
let sealed = try AES.GCM.seal(data, using: key)
```

Source: [WWDC 2019 Introducing iPad Apps for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/205/?time=2078)